# Bitwise comparison for 16 bitstrings

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, binary-data

I have 16 unrelated binary strings (of the same length). eg. 100000001010, 010100010010 and so on, and I need to find out a bitstring in which position x is a 1 IF position x is 1 for ATLEAST 2 bitstrings out of the 16.

Initially, I tries using bitwise XOR and this works great as long as even number of strings contain a 1, but when odd number of strings contain 1, the answer given is reverse.

```
A simple example (with 3 strings) would be:
A: 10101010
B: 01010111
C: 11011011

f(A,B,C)= answer

Expected answer: 11011011
Answer I'm getting right now: 11011001
```

I know I'm wrong somewhere but I'm at a loss on how to proceed
Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
unsigned once = x[0], twice = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 16; ++i) {
    twice |= once & x[i];
    once |= x[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C)

This is higher complexity than what you had originally.

Comment: but this is logical for 3 or max 4 variables. I have 16. Doing this seems impractical... isn't it?

Comment: Without knowing how you're storing the variables I can't really know.  If you have them in an array of N variables then your complexity would be O(N^2)

Comment: And you could do this using a nested for loop.